# A Webpack app can't be deployed properly on Google Cloud and Cloud Foundry

Tags: webpack, google-cloud-platform, cloud-foundry

I have a simple Vue client built with Vue CLI in terms of Webpack. It runs fine in my local Linux box. after I deploy it to Google Cloud, it isn't running. The followings are log messages when I hit the app Url.

```
2017-08-15 19:44:09 default[20170815t122042]
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]      throw err;
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]      ^
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  Error: Cannot find  module 'chalk'      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)      at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/check-versions.js:1:75)      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/bin/npm" "start"
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! node v6.11.2
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! supplier-vue@1.0.0 start: `node build/dev-server.js`
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR!
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! Failed at the supplier-vue@1.0.0 start script 'node build/dev-server.js'.
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR!     node build/dev-server.js
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR!     npm bugs supplier-vue
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  > supplier-vue@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-15 19:50:15 default[20170815t122042]  > node build/dev-server.js
```

After I install the module 'chalk', I still get the error. I just get the latest node.js and npm installed today.

I try to deploy the app to Cloud Foundry without a luck either.

```
2017-08-15T15:31:03.11-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Creating container
2017-08-15T15:31:03.76-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully destroyed container
2017-08-15T15:31:03.89-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully created container
2017-08-15T15:31:10.55-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Starting health monitoring of container
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR module.js:487
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     throw err;
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     ^
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR Error: Cannot find module '/home/vcap/app/supplier-vue.js'
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
2017-08-15T15:31:11.00-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR     at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
2017-08-15T15:31:11.02-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT Exit status 1
2017-08-15T15:31:11.02-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Exit status 0
2017-08-15T15:31:11.04-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Stopping instance d1d9f847-d52c-4c3c-5499-97a6
2017-08-15T15:31:11.04-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Destroying container
2017-08-15T15:31:11.12-0700 [API/2]      OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
2017-08-15T15:31:11.14-0700 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3d2511fc-5209-437c-9c9e-377ed10f8b6d payload: {"instance"=>"d1d9f847-d52c-4c3c-5499-97a6", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1502836271075038027, "version"=>"a275f709-e0aa-4520-9e28-e44c345c5c45"}
2017-08-15T15:31:12.17-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully destroyed container
```

Interesting! The above two set of error messages is different. After some online search, I haven't seen any information on any special things needed to be able to be deployed on the clouds. How to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you running it? I would not use Webpack to run something in production.

Comment: I mean deployment. Why should one not use Webpack in production? I follow this article : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-develop-vue2-bluemix/index.html

Comment: Webpack is a build tool. You can use it to output HTML and other assets, but the dev server is only suitable for development. In production you should either be serving those assets with a proper web server such as Nginx or using something like Express.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. Is any good tutorial for the process?

Comment: When pushing to CF, what command are you running?  What's the output of staging?  Is `supplier-vue.js` part of your app or supposed to be installed by npm?

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thanks for your questions. I use the information presented on https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html . Running the command:  cf push my-app -c "node my-app.js" There isn't a file with a name 'supplier-vue.js'. Matt pointed out that a Webpack app isn't for a product. It is much appreciated for any advice on how to convert such app so that it can be deployed to CF.

Comment: @vic - I don't know your app, is there any chance you could link me to a demo to replicate?  or a short set of instructions to replicate?

Comment: @DanielMikusa I only can run it on my local Linux box. I can let you have an access to my bitbucket repository once I get it uploaded. To do so, I need your email address for sending an invitation.

Comment: @vic - I don't need/want your whole app.  Could you just give me a very small and basic sample that just focuses on reproducing this issue?  Post it on a gist or something like that.

Comment: Webpack generates a project structure with a few files by default. The gist isn't suitable. Let me see what I can do on my side to make it easy for you.

Comment: @DanielMikusa My CF account is expired after a trial period. As a result, I can't do anything test about CF.